# How to apply css with native js when a button is clicked on the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to apply a style when clicking a button on the page. The button has a data-selector attribute. This attribute is the selector where I want to apply the css.

HTML example:

```
<ul>
<li><button class="button" data-selector="#skip > p > a">Button 1</button></li>
<li><button class="button" data-selector="#menu > div" >Button 2</button></li>
<li><button class="button" data-selector="#social">Button 3</button></li>
</ul>

<div id=#menu>
<div id="skip">
<p><a href="/pages">Hello</a></p>
</div>

<div id=social>
<p>Example 1</p>
<p>Example 2</p>
</div>
</div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
var error = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
    for (var i=0;i<error.length;i++){
        error[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            var selector = error[i].getAttribute('data-selector');
            selector.style.border = '2px solid red';
        }, false);
    }
</script>
```

**Result:**
error[i] is undefined

I'm using js native  because I can not use jQuery

PS:Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Please share your html as well

Comment: as well as your main error, looks like you are trying to apply the style to the selector variable which is just the text from your data attribute, not a dom element

Comment: what does console.log(error) returns?

Comment: Return: NodeList[button, button, button]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two errors. First, you are getting the selector string but never actually the DOM element that it represents. Second, you need to use `this` within the function context. Working code:

```
 var error = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
 for (var i=0;i<error.length;i++){
    error[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        var selector = this.getAttribute('data-selector');
        document.querySelectorAll(selector)[0].style.border = '2px solid red';
    }, false);
}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h5eqg4tp/